# Creating a project structure automatically

Tags: java, automation, project

I know there are tools for automatically creating a Java project structure: It will create src and bin folders and so on.

Is there a more general tool for creating general project structures (including both files and directories (perhaps copying over template files and filling in values in them)) based on information from, say, an input file?

Comment: why don't you write such an application. You can even make script files for this. like cmd files, or go for ruby or python.

Comment: If I wanted to, I would.  I have about a zillion ideas for projects that are more interesting to me, though.

Comment: thats good to know mate :) keep it up. i also share your enthusiasm.